# I want to get the public ip, but apache2 get the private ip

Tags: php, apache, ip

I want to get the public ip adress of my users but my code get the private ip... Do you know what's the problem ?

My code:

```
function get_ip()
{
        $ips = "";

        if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
            $ips .= ';'.$_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];

        if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
            $ips .= ';'.$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"]))
            $ips .= ';'.$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];

        if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
            $ips .= ';'.$_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"]))
            $ips .= ';'.$_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"];

        if(isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]))
            $ips .= ';'.$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    return $ips;

}
```

sometimes the function return ip as "10.46.40.246"... What's the best way to get the public ip ?
Thanks you !

Comment: I believe that you should only be able to see their private IP if they're on the same network as the web server. Is that the case?

Comment: Any `HTTP_X_..` / `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` is unreliable (I can easily set that extra header and claim I'm Google of Microsoft head office). If you trust the proxy (`REMOTE_ADDR`) that sets it, you _may_ use it, but based on the value (private ranges) you can opt not to. You don't know anything for sure except the last hop. It's a fact that you _cannot_ know for certain what the originating IP is if proxies are in use.

Comment: It's very strange... For 95% of the users of my site, the function work fine and I get the public ip. But for the others 5%, I get the private Ip.. Why ? I don't know... The server is an apache. all connexion to the server is on wan, not on lan.

Comment: And do you have a solution to get ip ...?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the anomalies you're seeing are from people behind a proxy in an office environment. If you always want the public IP, you'll probably just have to take `REMOTE_ADDR`. I suppose you could also use this function and fall back on `REMOTE_ADDR` if it returns something in a private IP block.

Comment: And do you have a solution to get ip ...?

Comment: I just gave you one. If either of the other headers you're checking report a private IP, then `REMOTE_ADDR` is the closest thing you're going to get to a public IP. Like I said, it probably means the user is behind a proxy that serves an internal network.

If `REMOTE_ADDR` reports a private IP, then someone is accessing your site on an internal network. What's your hosting environment like?